# Can't configure MIDDLEWARE for Auditlog actor_id in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-auditlog

The documentation says that to automatically take the actor_id, I need to install a piece of `auditlog.middleware.AuditlogMiddleware` code in `MIDDLEWARE`. I did just that but nothing worked, I still can’t write who changed it

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'auditlog.middleware.AuditlogMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

AUDITLOG_INCLUDE_ALL_MODELS = True
```

Other functions work correctly and without failures

Answer (score 1):

I think your `'auditlog.middleware.AuditlogMiddleware',` middlesware isn't in a right place, because you already put CORS middleware in a bad place. the CORS middleware must be placed before COMMON middleware not after that!
check the middleware place again or at least change its place in MIDDLEWARE settings.